# Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1) CS0200

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, serialization, permissions

I have a class which is being serialized/deserialized which works fine on most machines, but doesn't work on others (I have not been able to discern the difference, though on the boxes that present an issue I see other issues which have hints of "security/permission" issue [specifically my app can create a folder, but then can't write files to it... weird, but not the main issue]).

The error I get is:

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0200: Property or indexer 'Namespace.Object.ParentOrganizations' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

The following is the property:

```
    public List<long> ParentOrganizations
    {
        get
        {
            return m_OrganizationIDs;
        }
        internal set
        {
            m_OrganizationIDs = value;
        }
    }
```

And if I change the "set" to public it does work, but I want to know why I have to do this on only a few specific boxes... so I can help assess why this and the other *weird* issues are occurring. I figure fixing a single weird issue at a time in my app is more of a hassle (and likely wrong) versus finding and resolving a system configuration issue.

UPDATE: Giving localMachine\Everyone full permissions to the executing folder resolves this issue as well, but is not a good long-term solution.

Comment: Unless someone has had the same issue you do it's virtually impossible to diagnose and come up with a solution over a forum such as this. Please consider rephrasing or limiting you question to something specific that others might have a better chance of answering. More details about the environments. How does it execute on a blank machine? What is the exact diff in permissions? Etc can help others help you.

Comment: I understand this is a bit of a needle in a haystack sort of request, and I'm sorry for that. If someone could help point me in the direction of how best to narrow down from using "Everyone" to a more targeted user that would be enough to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using one of the Common serializers, you are facing the problem that the serializer self is simply not able to set the ParentOrganizations property because the `internal` access modifier limit the access to all callers that are not inside the same Assembly then the property is. This causes the serializer ( that is located in an other asseambly ) to throw this exception because he is not allowed to access the property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get what you're saying. But what I don't understand is why this works on some (actually most) other machines. I'm assuming there's some permission or configuration issue at play here that I'd like to track down (because this isn't the only issue I've seen, it's just a single symptom).

Comment: .NET Framework 4.0 versus 4.5 is where I'm seeing it. 4.5 is an in-place upgrade and thus may hide issues when you are targeting 4.0 (as it may fix some bugs that were present in 4.0). I'm assuming this is the case, I see it on Windows 2003, but not anywhere else. I'm guessing there is an issue with the serializer that was fixed between the two versions. Or that it works around internal/private sets properly.